# a way to test if you're on the first run of several recursive calls c++

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm was wondering if there's a way to check if you're on the first recursive call of a series of many recursive calls.

I'm working on a function that tests to see if the input is a palindrome.  After the last recursive call is over, the input string is changed to to the reverse of the original.  Now all I want to do is compare the result with the original.  But when the base case is reached, I no longer have access to the copy of the original string I made in the else statement.

My thought is then to compare `palCopy` with `palCheck` under the else statement but the problem with that is that the program will check this during EVERY recursive call when I only want to check it when control is returned to the original recursive call.  Is there a way to conditionally compare `palCopy` and `palCheck` only when control is returned to the original recursive call?

```
void isAPalindrome(MyString palCheck, int bound1, int bound2)
{

    if (bound1 >= bound2)
    {
        cout << palCheck;
    }
    else
    {
        MyString palCopy = palCheck;  // make a copy of the original argument so as not to alter it
        char temp = palCopy[bound1];
        palCopy[bound1] = palCopy[bound2];
        palCopy[bound2] = temp;
        isAPalindrome(palCopy, bound1 + 1, bound2 - 1); 
    }
```

Comment: It is a very inefficient way to do palindrome checking, and it doesn't really use the recursion for the check. You're using the recursion to reverse a string. So to separate the concerns I'd suggest making a separate function for reversing strings. Then your `isAPalindrome`-function becomes very simple. Additionally `isAPalindrome` sounds like a function that returns a bool and prints nothing. Otherwise rename it to `printIfPalindrome`;-)

Comment: Unless it is an assignment (that requires recursion) you may want to consider a different approach.

Comment: In this particular example, won't the value of `bound1` already show the recursion depth (zero-indexed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ has no primitive way to know if you are in the first recursion. But you could use a `level` variable, that counts the recursion depth. Something like:

```
void isAPalindrome(MyString palCheck, int bound1, int bound2, int level=0)
{
    if (bound1 >= bound2)
        cout << palCheck;
    else
    {
        MyString palCopy = palCheck;
        char temp = palCopy[bound1];
        palCopy[bound1] = palCopy[bound2];
        palCopy[bound2] = temp;
        isAPalindrome(palCopy, bound1 + 1, bound2 - 1, level+1);
        if (level == 0)
            // You are in the first recursion call
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer still makes a copy at every single iteration.

Comment: Use a static level check and reset it to zero or false when you reach the end case.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can track recursion depth by doing something like:

```
void recurse(int value, const int depth=0)
{
     recurse(value, depth+1); 
}
```

That is using an extra variable to for each of the calls which record the depth of recursion at any given point.

Comment: +1 for just answering the question, and not implementing the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't solve this problem this way, but never mind that.  The general way to do something like this is to move the recursion into a helper function that takes an extra argument:

```
static void 
is_palindrome_internal(string palCheck, int bound1, int bound2,
                       bool outermost)
{
   ...
   is_palindrome_internal(..., false);
   ...
}

void
is_palindrome(string palCheck, int bound1, int bound2)
{
   is_palindrome_internal(palCheck, bound1, bound2, true);
}
```

Then `outermost` will be true only when the current invocation is the outermost.  This approach also has the advantage that you can hide the `bound1` and `bound2` arguments from the public API (only do this if you don't ever want to operate on substrings, of course).

```
void
is_palindrome(string palCheck)
{
    is_palindrome_internal(palCheck, 0, palCheck.length(), true);
}
```

Comment: Even better with a default value `bool outermost=true`

Comment: I actually think that would be a mistake - whichever way you set the default, some caller is going to fail to think about it and get it wrong and the compiler won't catch it.

Comment: @Zack: The default is to implement the external interface. Remembering to pass `false` is an implementation detail which only matters internally.

Comment: The default value just means: _if you don't tell me anything, I'll guess it's true_, and in this case makes a lot of sense because if you are not passing explicitly outermost as false, then you have to be calling it from outside .. How could this lead to a problem?

Comment: If you set the default to be `false` (convenient for the actual recursive calls), external callers might get it wrong.  If you set it to be `true` (convenient for the external callers), the *implementation* risks getting it wrong.  In this case the only external caller is a wrapper function and there's only one recursive call, so I rate the odds of somebody getting it wrong as equal either way.  In real life I might choose to use a default `true` if it would eliminate the need for a wrapper function and there were many external callers and only one or two recursive calls.

Comment: ... I should maybe say that I have spent a lot of time hand-coding recursive descent parsers, in which you have *lots* of self-recursion and indirect recursion, and getting the "how deep are we" arguments wrong internally is a serious concern.

Answer (score 1):

You are already passing one copy of string as an arg. You can also pass a reference to the original string so that all levels of recursion have access to both.

```
void isAPalindrome(MyString palCheck, int bound1, int bound2 , const MyString& original )
{
//Do stuff

     isAPalindrome(palCopy, bound1 + 1, bound2 - 1,original); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a local struct so that `is_palindrome()` will accept just one argument:

```
bool is_palindrome(const std::string& s) 
{
   struct local
   {
      static bool is_palin(const std::string& s, int l, int h) 
      {
         return l>= h?true:(s[l] == s[h]? is_palin(s,l+1,h-1):false);
      }
   };
   return local::is_palin(s, 0, s.size() - 1);
}
```

Online demo : http://www.ideone.com/o1m5C

Use and modify it whichever way you want to.

Comment: Clever way to implement local functions.

Answer (score -2):

Make it a seperate function:

```
void isAPalindromeHelper(MyString& palCheck, int bound1, int bound2)
{
    if (bound1 >= bound2)
    {
        cout << palCheck;
    }
    else
    {
        char temp = palCopy[bound1];
        palCopy[bound1] = palCopy[bound2];
        palCopy[bound2] = temp;
        isAPalindromeHelper(palCopy, bound1 + 1, bound2 - 1); 
    }
}
void isAPalindrome(MyString palCheck)
{
    MyString palCopy = palCheck;  
    isAPalindromeHelper(palCheck, 0, palCheck.size()); 
    if (palCopy == palCheck)
        //newstuff here
}
```

Comment: It isn't really necessary to make a second function, when you can do the same with just one.

Comment: Removed the code duplication, making it easier to use and understand in the process.